# Why does backbone.js model.save() change the attribute hash?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am doing something like this in my code:

```
data_hash = {};
data_hash['some_model_key'] = 'A';
console.log(data_hash['some_model_key']); /* prints A */
model.save(data_hash,{
    wait:true,
    success:function(){
        console.log(data_hash['some_model_key']); /* prints B */
    }
});
```

I understand that if the server changes the state of the model and i am setting `wait:true` then my backbone model should receive the new value.  But why is my attribute hash being changed?

Comment: Actually what you see in console is the new hash. If you want to see the hash BEFORE model.save() and if you use underscore, do `console.log(_.clone(data_hash))` which will be the original hash, not the hash updated by server

Comment: But my question is, why does backbone change values in `data_hash` in my example.  It should only set the values in the `model`

Comment: Can you show XHR request and response? Just curious. Have you looked at what goes on on server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why Backbone changes your object

If you take a look at the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-57), you'll notice that in case of a `wait:true` option, the success callback extends the attr object with the server attributes.

```
    if (options.wait) {
      delete options.wait;
      serverAttrs = _.extend(attrs || {}, serverAttrs);
    }
```

And according to [Underscore doc](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), _.extend copies all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, overriding any previously defined property. Why it is the chosen behavior is a guess, but I suspect it is to keep all references in sync with the "real" state of the model. Or it's an unforeseen side effect.

Note that the first object you pass to `model.save` is expected to be attributes you want to set on your model as part of the save process. From [Backbone doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

> **save** *model.save([attributes], [options])*
>   The attributes hash (as in set) should contain the attributes you'd
>   like to change — keys that aren't mentioned won't be altered — but, a
>   complete representation of the resource will be sent to the server.

### What you can do to keep your object untouched

Pass a clone of your object to `model.save`:

```
model.save(_.clone(data_hash), ...)
```

Note: you don't need to have a `wait:true` option for your model to receive the values from your server, `model.set` will be always be called with the new values.

Comment: +1 for the reference from the annotated source.  I had read that.  I just dont get the rationale for changing the input to a function.

Comment: @mvblfst If he wants to compare what he has in the client vs what the server answered, I guess

Comment: @Yasser _.clone ? To have a different object on which Backbone can do whatever it wants and not modify your source object. But I may have read a bit too much in your question.

Comment: @nikoshr, again data_hash is not the object i am asking backbone to set/save.  `data_hash` is just an option hash, the "object" which needs to be changed/set is `model`

Comment: @Yasser Ha, ok, I went slightly on the wrong track. I'll modify my answer

Comment: IMO what's the point of checking if it was changed? `save()` already means you are saving a change. Than request should be handled by server and reply with error code or updated model, and appropriately handled again on the client side. The whole thing sounds very hack-ish.

Comment: @mvblfst nikoshr is right, i want to compare which values did the server update, so i want my option hash.  In general if i am passing something to a function as an argument, that argument should not be changed unless explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @Yasser Added a bit of info, but the conclusion would be the same, the first argument will end as a representation of your model

Comment: So this is more for debugging your server rather than client side, as I understand. The point is that there's no oddity here in how Backbone works and the less hacks you do now, the less headache you will have in the future. My five cents.